# Apache2 reverse proxy block access to files

Tags: linux, apache2, reverse-proxy

I'm using Apache2 2.4.46 as a reverse proxy in front of a docker container (Reverse proxy itself is not inside container). The container comes with a WordPress installation.
When I check the configuration with wpscan it shows me that there are some files presented that better should be hidden, like readme.txt or xmlrpc.php.

I try to hide them via directive:

```
<Files "readme.txt">
   Require all denied
</Files>
```

But that does not work.
I have also tried the old version:

```
<Files "readme.txt">
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
</Files>
```

I want to secure them globally for this instance. So I tried to set it outside of a  directive and also inside <Proxy "*">... directive.

All failed. Any ideas what to do? Or what could be wrong?

Regards
olaf

Answer (score 0):

You should instruct proxypass to ignore urls using the "!" notation.

```
ProxyPass /public/forms/ !
```

Official documentation here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass